# Proving an inverse continuous function has distribution $F$

Tags: probability-theory, monte-carlo, inverse-function

> Let $F$ be a continuous distribution function on $\mathbb{R}$, with its (generalized) inverse function $$F^{-1}(u) = \inf\{x: F(x) = u, 0 < u < 1\}$$
>   Prove the following statements:
>
> a.) If $U$ is uniform random variable on $(0,1)$, then $F^{-1}(U)$ has distribution function $F$.
>
> b.) If $X$ has distribution function $F$, then $F(X)$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$.

I normally do not post a question without an attempted solution but I am a bit lost here, I don't really understand what is being asked to prove. Any suggestions or comments are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Attempted proof a.) Suppose $U\sim U(0,1)$, then

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(F^{-1}(U)\leq x) &= \mathbb{P}(U\leq F(x))\\
&= \int_{0}^{F(x)}du\\ &= F(x)\\ 
\end{align*}
Not sure if this is correct or not but thats what I was thinking a.) wanted me to prove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property in b) is called [probability integral transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform). The proof is relatively straightforward using the *cdf* method.

Let $X$ be continuous r.v. with *cdf* $F_{X}$, then $Y=F_{X}(X)\sim\mathcal{U}[0,1]$. In fact, $F_{Y}(y)=\mathbb{P}[F_{X}(X)\leq y]=\mathbb{P}[X\leq F_{X}^{-1}(y)]=F_{X}(F_{X}^{-1}(y))=y$.

Comment: I see, so is my answer to part a.) correct?]

Answer (score 4):

You already have an answer to Part B, so I'll outline the proof for Part A that does not assume continuity of $F$. Firstly, I believe you meant to define $F^{-1}$ as follows: $$F^{-1}(u) = \inf\{x \, : \, F(x) \ge u,\, 0 < u < 1\}$$ This is how it is defined on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Inverse_distribution_function_(quantile_function)). Your proof is technically correct; it is true that the events $F^{-1}(U) \le x$ and $U \le F(x)$ are equivalent. However, this is not a trivial fact; you'll need to prove this. To do so, you can use the following line of reasoning:

Firstly, show that the infimum in the expression for $F^{-1}$ is always attained; that is, for any $u \in (0,1)$, $F^{-1}(u) \in \{x \, : \, F(x) \ge u\}$. You can do this using the right-continuity and nondecreasingness of $F$, which are two of the defining properties of CDFs.

Secondly, show that $F^{-1}$ is nondecreasing. You can do this using the fact that the infimum is attained.

Thirdly, show that, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $F^{-1}(F(x)) \le x$.

These three facts are enough to show via double containment that the events $F^{-1}(U) \le x$ and $U \le F(x)$ are equivalent, which completes your proof for Part A.